# Probability distribution of a Gaussian knowing that a variable is in a certain interval.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that we have a variable $X$ with a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma$. We also have a machine that tells us with 100% fiability if $|X|>\sigma$ or $|X|<\sigma$, I would like to know the probability density function of $X$ given that the machine told me that $|X|>\sigma$ (also the other probability density function, with $|X|<\sigma$). I thought about just renormalizing  the gaussian in the given intervals (I believe this would lead me to a wrong answer) or  using Bayes' Theorem, but I don't know how, could anyone give me hints/help? Thanks

Comment: Search for truncated distribution.

Comment: Thanks,So when $|X|<\sigma$ I just have to normalize. But when $|X|>\sigma$ truncated normal doesn't work? In wikipedia they don't explain this case when you have the gap in the middle.

Comment: Similar thing happens for the second case also :

Pdf of $X\mid |X|>\sigma$ is

$$f_{X\,\mid\,|X|>\sigma}(x)=\frac{f_X(x)}{P(|X|>\sigma)}\mathbf1_{|x|>\sigma}$$

, where $f_X$ is the pdf of $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by $1_{|x|>\sigma}$? (the factor that is multiplying the fraction)

Comment: That is a shorthand notation for an indicator variable meaning $$\mathbf1_{|x|>\sigma}=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }|x|>\sigma\\0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$